# client-side caching of jquery-ui-autocomplete: javascript/jquery regex to match a string "index" of an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-ui-autocomplete, javascript-objects

In my web app , i am using [jquery ui autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) which data are stored in the database **(Mysql**).

In this application, i have the administration official data **And** i enable the users to enter their own data. Data will be displayed in the autocomplete drop down list .
The **administration data** are limited and never change thus are preloaded and cached in memory, however the **user data** aren't (since user data grows exponentially and there is no point of using a database if all is to be cached in memory).

So i am doing multi levels caching in my web app, of which, i am caching autocomplete's **user data** on the client side (instead of getting them from db on each search).

**The scenario is as follow:**
When the app loads, the admin data (that are preloaded in memory) are loaded and cached in a JS object to be used in the autocomplete mechanism.

Thus when a user searches for a word, it will check the admin data JS object and if it can't find it, it will go to db and find it in user data.

So **for the case of searching user's data in db**, What i am doing right now is the following:

```
$( "#search" ).autocomplete({
source:function(request, response) {
var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(data, request.term);
if (request.term.toUpperCase() in autocomplete_cache) {
    response($.map(autocomplete_cache[request.term.toUpperCase()], function(item) {
     return {value: item.members.name, md5: item.members.ID}
    }))
   
    return;
   }
```

where **autocomplete_cache** is a javascript object:

```
var autocomplete_cache = {};
// ...it gets filled everytime a new $.post gets new data
...autocomplete_cache[request.term.toUpperCase()] = data;
```

For the moment, it is caching the  **exact term searched by a user**.

For example, if a user writes **"ABCD"** and which is not already cached :

**-->** go to the database (MySQL) do :***"WHERE term Like %ABCD%"*** 
**-->** autocomplete_cache["ABCD"] = *"data parsed from mysql"*

So if the same USER now retypes **"ABCD"** it will get it from the **autocomplete_cache Object**. 
However if the USER type **"ABC"** it won't get it from the cache object because of the line:

```
if (request.term.toUpperCase() in autocomplete_cache)
```

So what i would like to do is to match what the User types in the cache, so in this scenario if the User types **"ABC"** (which is contained in cache's **"ABCD"** String) , the autocomplete will build a drop down list containing **"ABCD"**.

Is there a way of doing that? the reason for this requirement instead of finding the exact String index in the cache object , it will find a wider range and thus limit probabilities of needing to go to db to find the new matches.

Comment: How could that logically work? If `abcd` is cached, and then they try `ab` and it finds `abcd` in the cache, you are getting the results for `abcd` and not `ab` which could mean possibly not seeing some results. Am I miss-understanding the question?

Comment: @KevinB i want the regex to match anything containing what the user types, for example : user types abc and you have abcd,abcde cached so the drop down will show: abcd,abcde ie all that contains abc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looking for a specific key, test each key whether the term is a substring:

```
var term = request.term.toUpperCase();
for (var key in autocomplete_cache) {
    if (key.indexOf(term) > -1) {
        // term is contained in key
    }
}
```

And instead of calling `response` on the first match, collect all matches’ items in an additional array and call `response` at the end:

```
var term = request.term.toUpperCase(),
    items = [];
for (var key in autocomplete_cache) {
    if (key.indexOf(term) > -1) {
        items.merge($.map(autocomplete_cache[key], function(item) {
            return {value: item.members.name, md5: item.members.ID}
        });
    }
}
if (items.length > 0) response(items);
```

You might also want to remove any duplicates in `items` and sort the resulting items before calling `response`:

```
var term = request.term.toUpperCase(),
    items = [],
    index = {};
for (var key in autocomplete_cache) {
    if (key.indexOf(term) > -1) {
        $.each(autocomplete_cache[key], function(item) {
            var id = item.members.ID;
            if (!index[id]) {
                items.push({value: item.members.name, md5: item.members.ID});
                index[id] = true;
            }
        });
    }
}
items.sort(function(a, b) { return a.name.localeCompare(b.name); });
if (items.length > 0) response(items);
```